# Hide/close container using uk-close button

Tags: html, css, getuikit

Is it possible to close the container using uk-close button? I find examples to close alerts and dialogs but how to close/hide containers?

```
<div class="uk-container uk-position-center">
  <div class="uk-width-xxlarge uk-height-large uk-card uk-card-body uk-card-default ">

    <button class="uk-close-large" type="button" uk-close></button>
      testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing tetesting testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing sting testing testing testing testing testing

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uk-close` is only available for Modals, but you can still use `uk-toggle` to open/close any element you want. You need to assign ID to your container and then you can toggle it with `uk-toggle="target: #id"` as shown in the example.
This may not to be the best solution as it requires adding container ID and uk-toggle, so maybe a custom event listener for that button would be better.

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.2.4/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.2.4/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.2.4/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

<div class="uk-container uk-position-center" id="toggled-container">
    <div class="uk-width-xxlarge uk-card uk-card-body uk-card-default">
      <button class="uk-close-large uk-align-right" type="button" uk-close uk-toggle="target: #toggled-container"></button>
      <p>testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing tetesting testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It definitely better than using custom JS attachment, this is a framework build in solution, so why to use pure JS when this is available!

Answer (score 0):

Give the container div a id and add a function that changes the display to 'none':

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="uk-close-large" type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('uk-container').style.display='none'"></button>
```

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer.

Comment: What detail would you like?